# post variable not being picked up on destination page

Tags: php, html, forms, variables, post

I have a form that is generated using PHP on one page called product, which gives the user the option of a drop down box. The form is then submitted using the post method to the cart page, however the cart page does not pickup the posted variable? How do I store the posted variable?

Here is my code:

Product Page Html:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" action="nav/cart.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="<?php echo $targetID; ?>">
    <?php echo $shipping?>
    <button class="btn btn-custom" name="submit" id="submit" type="submit">Add To Cart</button>
</form>
```

Product Page PHP:

```
$shipping = '<select class="form-control" name="shippingType" id="shippingType" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
                        <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                        <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
                        <option value="Worldwide">Worldwide</option>
                    </select>';
```

Cart Page PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['shippingType'])){
    $shippingType = $_POST['shippingType'];
};
```

Comment: What is the value of `$_POST`? (e.g. `echo"<pre>".print_r($_POST,true)."</pre>";`)

Comment: Looks ok to me. Is `$_POST['pid']` ok? I don't think it's that, but can you change the button for an `<input type="submit">`? Also, can you show us the contents of `$_POST` and `$_SERVER`?

Comment: this should work, try to use echo i think its going to display the value